# TSQL - use columns as date range

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

[image: Table1]

How can I retrieve the cto column using an @variable?

For example, for `@Variable = '2019-03-02'` the expected output is`'MAR 1 - MAR 7'`.

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Please take a look at [mcve] for details about how to ask a great question.  Thanks!

Comment: BETWEEN operator may use both constant/literal expression and field/fields combination/expression both in tested part and in any/all range borders. So `@variable BETWEEN field1 AND field2` is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a barebone question, but...

@DateToUse is the date you are searching for.

@StringOutput is the cto column.

I'm using the ID field as a tie-breaker in order to protect against duplicate or overlapping ranges in from/to fields.

```
DECLARE @DateToUse DATE
DECLARE @StringOutput VARCHAR(50)

SET @DateToUse = '3/2/2019'

SET @StringOutput = (SELECT TOP (1) cto FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE @DateToUse BETWEEN from AND to ORDER BY ID)

PRINT @StringOutput
```